# What's the difference between grep "str" . and grep "str" *

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

In `grep "str" *`
Does it mean grep everything where `grep` executed?
and what about  `grep -r "str" .` which has more results than the former one

Comment: You'll get a faster answer by reading by yourself the `grep` manual and info pages, e.g. by typing `man grep`, `info grep` and even `grep --help`; also googling for `linux grep` gives a lot of relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `grep str *`, the shell will expand the `*` to match all filenames in the current directory, unless they start with a dot, and will then pass that list of files to the `grep` command.

When you run `grep -r str .`, the shell has nothing to expand itself. The `grep` command, however, reacts to the `-r` option by going through its argument list and *recursively* descending into all directories.

So, there are at least three differences:

- `grep -r` will find hidden files
- `grep -r` will go through subdirectories
- `grep -r` also works in directories with lots of files. You may get an error message saying the command line gets too long for `grep str *` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep
```

Will search for a pattern, the last argument is the files to search, so:

```
grep str *
```

Will search all files in the current directory(matched with * as a wildcard) for the pattern "str".

```
grep -r str .
```

Will search Recursively(so inside directories and such) for the pattern str starting with the current directory(the single dot is the current dir, two dots is the previous dir).

Answer (score 0):

```
grep  "str" * # search a string str in all files in current directly but not sub directories 
grep -r "str" . # search a string str recursively in cireent directory and in all sub directories in all file whose file name has a single character
```

Answer (score 0):

bash always expand * ? [...] ..  if you did not set noglob

when you use "." , grep will search from current directory, but when you use one of
above symbols, bash expands your command, then call grep